# Padding on search box not working for IE and chrome for bootstrap menu bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used this

```
.navbar-form .form-group {
padding-top: 30px;
display: inline;
}
```

to get the search box vertically centered on the bootstrap menu bar, but for some reason IE and Chrome does not recognize the padding-top:30px. Fire fox adjust to the padding quite fine.

How can I get this search box in IE and Chrome to pad properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this bootply: http://www.bootply.com/D27W6qcvVF

Your css should be like:

```
.navbar-form {
   padding-top: 30px;
   display: inline;
}
```